# Dynamic memory allocation and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, fgets

I'm struggling with pointers and their allocation.
I'd like to understand if I'm allocating correctly and how it should be done otherwise.
Also, I get warnings regarding the fgets and puts function but I think it is related to a wrong allocation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

const int n = 30, m = 30;

struct employer { 
    char *name[3][1];
    char *pass[n][m];
    int *ID;
};

int main() {
    struct employer admin;
    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        admin.name[i][1] = (char*)calloc(1, n); 
    }
 
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        fgets(admin.name[i][1], n, stdin);
        puts(admin.name[i][1]);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the warnings that I get:

- array index 1 is past the end of the array (which contains 1 element) [-Warray-bounds]";
- array index 1 is past the end of the array (which contains 1 element) [-Warray-bounds]";
- array index 1 is past the end of the array (which contains 1 element) [-Warray-bounds]";

They are related to the line were I allocated, the fgets fcn line and puts fcn line respectively.
Could you please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Array indices start at 0.

Comment: What is the point of an array that only contains one char pointer?

Comment: In `main` you have assigned to `i` but not declared it.

Comment: It is not C language.

Answer (score 0):

Three issues with your code. First you have used `i` in `main` but not declared it. Second, you are addressing index `1` in an array with length `1`. Since arrays are idnexed starting at `0`, you should be using index `0`. Third, dimensions of arrays in C must be constant expressions. As such, I've replaced your `const int` declarations with preprocessor directives to define `N` and `M`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 30
#define M 30

struct employer { 
    char *name[3][1];
    char *pass[N][M];
    int *ID;
};

int main(void) {
    struct employer admin;
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        admin.name[i][0] = (char*)calloc(1, N); 
    }
 
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        fgets(admin.name[i][0], N, stdin);
        puts(admin.name[i][0]);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

It is questionable as to why you would want an array of length 1. This gets you nothing over simply `char *name[3]`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 30
#define M 30

struct employer { 
    char *name[3];
    char *pass[N][M];
    int *ID;
};

int main(void) {
    struct employer admin;
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        admin.name[i] = (char*)calloc(1, N); 
    }
 
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        fgets(admin.name[i], N, stdin);
        puts(admin.name[i]);
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```

In practice, you should check to see if your allocation succeeded before proceeding under the assumption that it has.

You'd also want to `free` any memory you've dynamically allocated. For such a small program, it's likely that the OS you're running will automatically free the memory when the program stops, but it's not a bad habit to get into.

Of course, for such a trivial program where the bounds of the arrays are known, it's questionable whether dynamic allocation was ever really needed at all.

Comment: Yes, and it compiled cleanly without warnings using `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: I was using GCC, but I see the error now.

Comment: If N is contant expression what is the point of `malloc`?

Comment: Indeed. The only point I can see is not wanting to make a copy of 90 characters every time one of those structs is passed to a function. Of course, it's already copying _900_ char pointers courtesy of the `pass` member.

Comment: Why do you want to pass them by value?

Answer (score 0):

> I get warnings regarding the fgets and puts function but I think it is
> related to a wrong allocation.

No, it is not related to dynamic memory allocation

`char *name[3][1];` has only one column.

You try to access the **second** column as you use index `1`

```
admin.name[i][1]
              ^
              |---------- here
```

## Indexes in ***C*** (and ***C++***) start from `0`

To access the first column you need to:

```
admin.name[i][0]
```

## The following is not a valid `C`.

It is *C++* with GCC extensions and it won't compile if you use ***`C`*** language compiler.

```
struct employer { 
    char *name[3][1];
    char *pass[n][m];
    int *ID;
};
```

Also this:

```
int main() {
    struct employer admin;
    i = 0;
```

will not compile. You need to define `i`

```
int i = 0;
```

Also in C language do not cast the result of the `malloc` family functions.
***Remember to free allocated memory!!!***

Comment: _and C++_ and many many many other languages too. Spending some time getting used to this pays off down the road.

Comment: @Chris  elaborate please

Comment: Not directed at you. Just emphasizing the importance of this point.